# Passing a value to a global variable for reference with WinForms (C#) and SQL Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, radio-button, global-variables

I need two global variables to be accessed by multiple winforms at various stages.

The first is in regards to a distinct user, after logging in to the app,
other winforms need to get data from sql server tables based on the user who logged in.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM regClient WHERE client_ID = **[GLOBAL VARIABLE]**", con);
```

---

The second follows this in that the user can log in as either a **Client** or **Student**. Different statements need to be called based on this. This value is set by radiobutton on the login window.

So if radClient is checked set global to 'client', if radStudent is checked set global to 'student'
then with other winforms can call select statements or enable/visible based on what the global is.

---

I believe I can store variables in **Programs.cs** but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a User class:

```
public class User
{
    public enum eStatus
    {
         Client,
         Student
    }

    public static eStatus Status { get; set; }

    public static string Name { get; set; }  
}
```

You didn't say what the one variable is, so I guessed it was some kind of identifier like their name.

You can set the User's status with:

```
User.Status = User.eStatus.Client;
```

and the name with:

```
User.Name = "Charlie";
```

You can access and set the values from anywhere.

**Comment response:**

The if would look like:

```
if (Program.User.Status == Program.User.eStatus.Client)
{
   // commands
}
else // if (Program.User.Status == Program.User.eStatus.Student)
{
   // commands
}
```

You don't need the second if since there are only two values `User.Status` can have.

Comment: Where do I declare said class? I'm not familiar with this concept, how can I call the "username" (or what ever i set) for sql, and the status?

Comment: @NathanMackie If your using Visual Studio you can right click the project that your program.cs file is in and using the Add option choose class.  Then name the file User.cs and you will be given the stub of the User class to fill in.  Otherwise the class can go in the same file as the program.cs or another file you create in the same folder as the program.cs with the same namespace for simplicity.  As for the second part, you should ask that as a separate question with the details of "what ever i set" defined so you can get answers that are detailed as well.

Comment: Ahh, right.
I've placed the Class.User in Program.cs needing to call it in winforms with an if statement.

Comment: if (Program.User.Status.Client = true) then
{
commands
} else if (Program.User.Status.Student = true) then
{
commands
}

Comment: @NathanMackie You probably already figured it out since you marked my response as the answer, but I wrote how the if would look as an edit to my post.